# SCCM Powershell edit TaskSequence settings using Set-CMTaskSequence

Tags: powershell, module, sccm, configurationmanager, scmmanager

Trying to change what OS my TS supports in order to hide/show it in **Software Center**.

Importing ConfigurationManager.psd1 module and according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/set-cmtasksequence?view=sccm-ps) for **Set-CMTaskSequence** I should be able to specify which OS that should be supported:

[image]

If I manually set a specific OS and then want to undo following code change my TS back to **"Run on any platform"**:

```
Set-CMTaskSequence -TaskSequenceId XYZ00023 -RunOnAnyPlatform
```

The code i'm currently trying to set specified OS gives error:

[image]

```
Set-CMTaskSequence -TaskSequenceId XYZ00023 -AddSupportedOperatingSystemPlatform (Get-CMSupportedPlatform | Where-Object {$_.CI_UniqueID -eq 'Windows/All_x64_Windows_8.1'})
```

It doesn't mather which OS I'm trying to set same error occur everytime.

Anyone tried and successfully changed this value using Powershell and can assist in how to?

Comment: Using `-Verbose` a warning is shown: `WARNING: Unsupported platform 'All x64 Windows 8.1 devices' for task sequence.`

Comment: Indeed I get that warning too. As shown in my post. I did mention that this is shown no mather what OS I try to set. Clearly something not working configuring the value as I do. Thats why I asked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `-Verbose` a warning is shown: `WARNING: Unsupported platform 'All x64 Windows 8.1 devices' for task sequence.`

Found the solution here: https://blog.adexis.com.au/2019/06/14/sccm-windows-10-no-longer-ticked-as-deployment-target-os-for-packages-and-tss-after-upgrade-to-current-branch/

You should use the OS denoted with `client`:

```
$os = Get-CMSupportedPlatform -Fast | Where-Object { $_.CI_UniqueID -eq "Windows/All_x64_Windows_8.1_Client" }
Set-CMTaskSequence -TaskSequenceName "XYZ00023" -AddSupportedOperatingSystemPlatform $os -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks I manged to get it to work now.